# Zend Framework without using Zend Tool

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

I've already search before asking, and i just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950867/zend-framework-without-the-zend-tool). It seems that i didn't do the correct thing so here i'm posting it again.

If i don't use the Zend Tool to create Controllers and their Actions, should i edit the file .zfproject.xml manually?

Can i use both techniques? I mean some controllers created with Zend Tool (the first ones i created), and some without? Would the .zfproject.xml have problems then?

I think all my chaos comes from the .zfproject.xml file!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add controllers and everything manually, there is no need to update the zfproject.xml file.
When you want to mix and match it might cause problems in conflicting situations, you should be aware of that. But generally, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: So, if i already have a project created with Zend Tool, i should continue using it or manually add controllers and actions and then edit the zfproject.xml file. Am i right?

Comment: That is of course the safest way, but I think I wouldn't bother. Just remember to not add a controller/action/whatever using zend tool with a name you already have.